# Ajax request cannot access Api server

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller, server

we are developing an application with three tiered architecture say, web server, api server(local) and db server (local).

web application and api application are developed using c# mvc framework, i have a problem with calling apis from web server. There are two cases:

1. some apis are called from controller
2. some are called directly from ajax request.

Now the problem is when api server keeps locally only the 1 case apis are only working but 2 type apis are not working. This works fine when api server can access publically. Now the creteria is that apis server cant be public.

How can i solve this issue with minimal change.

Thanks

Comment: we need [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: "when api server keeps locally only the 1 case apis are only working but 2 type apis are not working" doesn't make any sense. Can you explain more clearly? Can you post an error message or explain why it isn't working?